# Ajax Update Panel Not Working Linkbutton Inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, repeater

I want to update control of update panel from repeater.

Repeater has one Linkbutton and operation is done on repeater's ItemCommand event

Kindly check below code and suggest me something.

```
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrCategory" runat="server"
                            OnItemCommand="rptrCategory_ItemCommand">

                            <ItemTemplate>

                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass='<%# (Container.ItemIndex==0)?"active clsCategory":"clsCategory" %>' ID="lnkCategory" runat="server" CommandName="Category" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CategoryID")%>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Category")%>'></asp:LinkButton>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>

                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rptrCategory" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptrQuestion" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:addQuestion(escape('<%# Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Question")).Replace("'","\\'") %>'));">
                                                <asp:Label ID="litQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Question")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litAlter" runat="server" Text='<%# GetAlterText(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("QuestionID")), Eval("AlterText").ToString(), Eval("AlterInfo").ToString()) %>'></asp:Literal>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where is your linkbutton inside update panel?

Comment: link button is out side the update paneln it's in "rptrCategory" repeater